# Where can a C++/Java developer find C# learning materials?

Tags: c#

I have a background of programming in Java and C++, so I know all about basic logic and OOP. However I'm at a new job and they are a C# coding company.

Are there any good tutorials/examples out there that show the specific differences between these languages, or at least show me the features of C#?

I briefly looked at the MSDN and looked over their 'intro to C#' but that was way too basic for my needs. Will I just have to poke around the MSDN a little more in depth and come up with ideas on my own about little test projects to get my feet wet in C#?

Comment: What kind of applications are you building, WinForms, web, etc?

Comment: Just got here so I haven't dug in too deep but, its billing software. So all i can tell you is its a lot of GUI and database stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN has their Ramp up website - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/default.aspx

Specifically for Java developers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/bb421266.aspx

Answer (score 2):

These links sounds promising:
[C# from JAVA](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html)
[C# from C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx)

Comment: C# from C++ is a little outdated, being based on C#1.0, nice links all the same.

Comment: Actually, i just googled. For me it's backwards - have to learn c++ a bit for university. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recomend the MSFT study guide for the 70-536 exam.
[http://www.amazon.com/MCTS-Self-Paced-Training-Exam-70-536/dp/0735626197/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1245687096&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626197)

It'll give you a good overview of .net & c# without pretending you are a high school kid who knows nothing about compilers.

Answer (score 1):

try one of these books you won't regret it:

Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform, Fourth Edition

or

Accelerated C# 2008

Answer (score 1):

The video tutorials on http://www.asp.net/learn are invaluable for asp.net programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you went to [Learn Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336766.aspx) and found none of the resources to be useful to you, including the [books](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336795.aspx), then you're doing pretty well - get to work!

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/) by Charles Petzold.